# How to implement expiry dates for a user account in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm building an application using express on the backend coupled with mongodb as my database and react on the front end. I will be having premium features that can only be accessed by payment. So I was thinking of using the PayPal api for this. i plan on having a field in my user model whether or not they are subscribed. How do I implement an automatic job to set the status of this premium field to false when the expiry date time has passed. Do I do a cron job for this? I'm abit lost.

Comment: This is generally a bit broad since there are many ways to approach this. One thing is MongoDB runs it's own periodic "cleanup" with [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/), which might be preferable to setting up a separate service or cron job. Worth a read.

Comment: @NeilLunn If TTL Index is used then the whole document will expire right?! So, I think, creating another collection for subscription and linking it to the user can be done here, if one is willing to use TTL Indexes.